# Looking for best way to refactor a large class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I have a situation whereby a predecessor has created a class that is designed to handle the creation of Note entities that are added to the database to journal actions that are carried out by the system across the site.

At present, this class has been broken down into several CreateXYZNote methods that take an enum denoting a specific note type, and an instance of the model that drives that area of the site.

My problem is, there are so many types of notes, each used only in one or two places across the system.  Each of the methods is huge, consisting of a small amount of common code, and specifics (e.g. the textual content of the note) are held within a series of switch statements based on an enum.  Extremely hard to find the code relating to specific notes, and very hard to maintain at present, and it's only going to grow as new types of notes find their way into the system over time.

Has anyone got any advice or patterns that could help with this sort of situation?

The simplest solution I can think of is that I have a set of profiles held outside of this class as a dictionary (keyed by the enum values) that define the title, description, categories etc. for the notes, and this class then becomes just a means of looking up those values and creating the note, but it just feels like I'm moving the problem to another place rather than resolving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `NoteFactory` that has a `INote Create(NoteType type)` method. The factory could depend on a Dictionary keyed by `NoteType` that the factory uses to find and return the appropriate `Note`. This way you avoid a non-OCP `switch` statement.

The factory can be injected with the dictionary, using an IoC container helps here, or you can create the dictionary in the constructor.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a good option.  Like the fact it would encapsulate that creation logic and takes it out of the rest of the note logic in the existing class.